# Prove the functor is not representable

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $F$ be the functor from rings to sets that takes a ring R to the set of all pairs $(a,b)\in R \times R$ such that $aR + bR = R$.  Show that $F$ is not representable.

This is a 2019 UCLA qualifying exam question.  I have tried using that if $(a,b)$ is a universal element in a ring $R$, then so is $(b,a)$.

Comment: Your solution seems promising. What prevented you from concluding?

Comment: Well the universal element is not unique.  It's unique up to unique isomorphism.  So I let $i: R\rightarrow R$ be the unique isomorphism that takes $(a,b) \rightarrow (b,a)$.  Then I tried to show that the map $\psi: R\rightarrow R$ that takes $(a,b) \rightarrow (1,0)$ has issues when we try to make it factor through $\psi \circ i$, but I just couldn't see the problem.

Comment: Did you do part (a) of the question? It helps :)

Comment: Small note: the problem on the exam says that the domain of this functor is the category of *commutative* rings. Doesn't make too much difference, but this might change which proofs are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let $k$ be a field.

---

**Lemma** As subrings of $k(x,y)$, we have $k[x,y] = k[x,y,x^{-1}] \cap k[x,y,y^{-1}]$.

*Proof*. Clearly, we have $k[x,y] \subseteq k[x,y,x^{-1}] \cap k[x,y,y^{-1}]$. Next, let $p \in k[x,y,x^{-1}] \cap k[x,y,y^{-1}]$ be arbitrary. Then we have $p = f/x^n$ and $p = g/y^m$ for some $f,g \in k[x,y]$ and $n,m \geq 0$. This yields $y^m f = x^n g$, so $y^m$ divides $x^n g$, whence $y^m$ divides $g$, so $p = g/y^m \in k[x,y]$. $\square$

**Corollary** The following is a pullback square in the category of (commutative) rings:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
k[x,y] @>>> k[x,y,y^{-1}]\\
@VVV @VVV \\
k[x,y,x^{-1}] @>>> k(x,y)
\end{CD}

---

Now, suppose for contradiction that $F$ is representable. Then $F$ preserves limits, so in particular the following would be a pullback square in the category  of sets:

\begin{CD}
F(k[x,y]) @>>> F(k[x,y,y^{-1}]) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
F(k[x,y,x^{-1}]) @>>> F(k(x,y))
\end{CD}

Moreover, we see directly that $F$ preserves inclusions (if $f : R \to S$ is an inclusion, then $F(f) = (a,b) \mapsto (f(a),f(b)) : F(R) \to F(S)$ is an inclusion). Thus, we have
$$F(k[x,y]) = F(k[x,y,x^{-1}]) \cap F(k[x,y,y^{-1}])$$
However, this is not true, since $(x,y) \in F(k[x,y,y^{-1}]) \cap F(k[x,y,x^{-1}])$ but $(x,y) \notin F(k[x,y])$.