# representable functors and finitely generated algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, representable-functor

I'm bothered by a confusing statment on representable functors.
Let $k\rm Alg$ be the category of finitely generated $k$-algebra ($k$ is a field) and $F:k\rm Alg\to Set$ a functor. Let $B={\rm Nat}(F,U)$ where $U$ is the forgetful functor $U:k\rm Alg\to Set$, i.e. the functor represented by $k[t]$. Then $B$ is a $k$-algebra and $F$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Hom}(B,-)$. I have trouble to figure out the element of $F(B)$ corresponds to ${\rm id}:B\to B$. Can any one tell me what is it?

Comment: One can actually prove the statement by employing a filtered colimit. But is there a more direct proof?

Comment: What is the $k$-algebra structure on $B$? It's not even immediately clear to me that $B$ is a set. Moreover, this can't be correct as stated, since this would imply that *every* functor $k\mathrm{Alg} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is representable. This is not the case; for example see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4050582/19006) -- my answer shows that the restriction of the given functor to the category of finitely generated $k$-algebras is not representable.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk the $k$-algebra structure comes from $k[t]$. Your comment reminds me that the statement cannot have a proof without using the filtered colimit of $k[t]$, or a purely categorical proof using nothing about finitely generated $k$-algebras.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand. Can you explain exactly what the sum and product of two natural transformations $a, b : F \to U$ is? You also did not address the main issue: no matter what the $k$-algebra structure on $B$ is, it cannot always be true that $F \cong \operatorname{Hom}(B,{-})$, or else every functor $k\mathrm{Alg} \to \mathrm{Set}$ would be representable, which is not the case (even by objects in the category of rings!)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk for example, $a+b$ maps $x\in F(R)$ to $a(x)+b(x)\in R$ for any f.g. $k$-algebra $R$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk the category $k{\rm Alg}$ here is of finitely generated $k$-algebras only and I'm sorry not to mention that $k$ is a field, so they are finitely presented $k$-algebras.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the ring structure on $B$, modulo size issues. However, I still don't understand how this representability is not an issue. Are $k[x,y]$, $k[x,y,x^{-1}]$, $k[x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}]$ objects of your category? If so, the functor $F(R) = \{(a,b) \in R \times R : Ra + Rb = R\}$ cannot be representable, since it does not preserve limits (see the link I posted above). (Note that $k[x,y,x^{-1}]$ is a finitely presented $k$-algebra, since it is isomorphic to $k[x,y,z]/(xz-1)$)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk $k(x,y)$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: There's no need to involve $k(x,y)$ -- you can replace it by $k[x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}]$ everywhere and everything will take place in your category of finitely generated $k$-algebras.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I feel you are right.